# React application is not working with store, reducer and provider import

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-redux

In my react application, I created store.js and rootreducer.js for it. Before creating the store.js and rootreducer.js file, my react application was working properly but after adding it, I'm actually not getting any error but my output on the local host is blank now. For including the store and reducer in my application I have imported the provider and store to my app.js file. If I remove them, my react application works properly but with these imports, I get a blank screen in my localhost. Below given is my store.js file

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import rootReducer from './Reducer/rootReducer';

const initialState = {}
const middleWare = [thunk]
let store;

if (window.navigator.userAgent.includes("Chrome")) {
    store = createStore(rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(applyMiddleware(...middleWare),
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
            window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
        ))
} else {
    store = createStore(rootReducer,
        initialState,
        compose(applyMiddleware(...middleWare)))
}

export default store;
```

And this is my app.js file

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Nav from './Component/Common/Nav';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Welcome from './Component/Welcome';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Dashboard from './Component/Dashboard/Dashboard';
import CreateMonthWallet from './Component/Dashboard/DashboardOperations/CreateMonthWallet';
import NotFound from './Component/Common/NotFound';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './Store';

//import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Nav />
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<Welcome />} exact />
            <Route path="/Dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} exact />
            <Route path="/CreateMonthWallet" element={<CreateMonthWallet />} exact />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} exact />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </Router>
      </Provider>
  );
}


export default App;
```

And this is my rootreducer.js file

```
import {combineReducers} from 'redux'

export default combineReducers({

});
```

Comment: in your app.js is `import store from './Store';` is it right or is store smaller ??

Comment: It is exactly the same.

Comment: https://enappd.com/blog/redux-in-react-native-app/92/ see here

Answer (score 0):

you can add your store like this in app.js

your code

```
import store from './Store';
```

add this

```
import {store} from './Store';
```

hope this will help you!